# Securing SAML auth

Tags: php, saml, onelogin

I was asked to add the possibility to use OneLogin to connect on our platform.

I used the [official php-saml example](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml) provided, made all the configurations needed and everything is working fine with OneLogin.

My question is : is it secure as it is ? as you can see in my `metadata.xml` below, i'm not using`AuthnRequestsSigned` or `WantAssertionsSigned` (still had to add the `x509cert` though).

Here is the metadata.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
                         validUntil="2018-01-12T15:32:08Z"
                         cacheDuration="PT604800S"
                         entityID="https://xxxx.com/sso/onelogin/metadata.php">
        <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
            <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                                    Location="https://xxxx.com/sso/onelogin/app/index.php?sls" />
            <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
            <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                                         Location="https://xxxx.com/sso/onelogin/app/index.php?acs"
                                         index="1" />

        </md:SPSSODescriptor>
    </md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: StackOverflow is a community specifically for programming questions, and since security isn't the focus of this community, I'd suggest asking your question on the [InfoSec](https://security.stackexchange.com/) community for better responses. Also your question doesn't pinpoint a specific problem, instead asking for advice. See how to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks but i asked there and got no answers